# Event on label is not updating the clicked label

Tags: c#

I want to add a event for label when a specific label is pressed, but my event handler is not reacting to the clicked label.

I created a calender so when I click a date I want to highlight that date, that's the requirement.

```
for (Int32 i = 1; i <= Dayz; i++)
{
    ndayz += 1;
    lblDayz = new Label();
    lblDayz.Text = i.ToString();
    lblDayz.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    lblDayz.Name = "Date" + i;
    lblDayz.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
    lblDayz.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

    lblDayz.Click += lblDayz_Click;
}
```

Event handler looks like:

```
public void lblDayz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDayz.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(176, 180, 43);
    lblDayz.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: the "object sender" parameter is the label that was clicked. Does that help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question? Please, edit your post and add it.

Comment: noo sry,
i called the event where i want the 'lblDayz' label to have that event

Comment: Are you asking how to subscribe your method to `lblDayz.Click`?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question again can u please refer it again

Comment: You're only showing the event handler method though. Do you have somewhere where you hook up this handler to an event on the label? Can we see that too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Label Click Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979929/label-click-event)

Comment: added that part as well,  any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation is trying to change the properties of `lblDayz`, which might be a single label somewhere. But the way you're creating labels you have a number of labels generated in code. One for each day

That means you need your handler to react to the label *that was clicked*. The label that was clicked is the `sender` in your event handler. Crudely then you could handle it like this

```
public void lblDayz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label clickedLabel = sender as Label; 

    clickedLabel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(176, 180, 43);
    clickedLabel.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: Okay,
Got this error afterwards,
'object' does not contain a definition for 'ForeColor' and no extension method 'ForeColor' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Then you didn't copy it properly

Comment: Thank you alot it Solved my Major Question, :-)
A small question came after that which is if i select another value the previous value also is been selected,
please provide a solution for it

Comment: You'd need something to either find and cycle through all your previous labels to deselect them. Or maybe something to remember the current (previous) selected label so that you can deselect it.  If you're still struggling then I'd suggest you ask a new question rather than try to clutter this one up.